# Overlapping Tabs JS CSS HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlapping

I ran into an issue today with an html/css map I am designing.  For some reason the tabs are overlapping each other causing the text to be difficult to read and otherwise offsetting the functionality of the map. If anyone knows how to fix this issue please let me know. You can find a sample of the site below.

http://mikedemar.com/martygraff/index.html

Thanks in advance,

- Mike

Comment: What do you mean that the tabs are overlapping? After all, you can only view one at a time. Do you mean that the blue location markers are covering the tabs? Try `z-index`, then.

Comment: Yes I mean the blue location markers. Sorry should have been a little more specific. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or, you could remove z-index values from the css classes and use jQuery to add / remove higher z-index values to the current div:

```
$('.handle').on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).css('z-index', '200000000');
});
$('.handle').on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).css('z-index', '100000000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `.handleicon` z-index aswell as the `.topdiv` z-index from the css and change the `.handleinfo` z-index to 999. that should solve your problam.

Good luck :)